# В чём ошибка с конструктором класса?

Tags: php, ооп

В ООП опыт небольшой, набросал класс что бы его конструктор сразу создал объект соединения с БД, но ошибки `Warning: Missing argument 1 for DB::__construct()` для всех 5 переменных. Я понимаю что он говорит что пропущен аргумент (типа его нет) но не понимаю почему. Вот же они выше!

```
class DB
{
    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $db =   'name'; 
    protected $charset = 'utf8';
    protected $user = 'user'; 
    protected $pass = 'passw';

    public function __construct($host, $db, $charset, $user, $pass) {

        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );

        try {
            $this->DBconnect = $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
        }
        catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
            if(!empty($Exception->getCode())){
                die('Ошибка');
            }
        }
    }
}

    // Создаю экземпляр
    $a = new DB();
```

Comment: покажи как создаешь экземпляр класса! `Вот же они выше!`  - кто? где?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский добавил создание экземпляра, тут всё просто `$a = new DB();`

Comment: `new DB();` - ты вообще ни одного аргумента не передаешь, а конструктор принимает аж 5. Если у тебя параметры в классе прописаны, то конструктор тогда и надо делать пустым

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не понял, так я что должен писать `$a = new DB($host, $db, $charset, $user, $pass);` это что за уродство, всё же внутри класса задано уже необходимое? Я чё-т не понимаю как правильно передать

Comment: Конструктор - это функция. Если ты прописываешь аргументы. то будь добр передай их в неё. А если ты объявил поля внутри класса, то на кой ляд ты тогда пишешь, чтоб у тебя конструктор принимал параметры?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ок, я сделал `$a = new DB($host, $db, $charset, $user, $pass);` и всё заработало если переменные вынести из класса что бы они были видны. Как использовать для конструктора переменные которые внутри класса? Надо писать `public function __construct($this->$host, $this->$db` и т.д.?

Comment: внутри класса - да (если они там объявлены), как аргументы функций - как написано в примере...

Comment: `__construct($this->host, $this->db, $this->charset, $this->user, $this->pass)`

Comment: @DaemonHK это бред

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский почему бред на сколько я понимаю это единственный работоспособный вариант что бы использовать именно эти переменные а не какие-то извне?

Comment: @fosh4455 использовать внутри класса - да (если они объявлены в классе), использовать такое описание в качестве аргументов конструктора класса выбьет ошибку - догадаетесь почему?

Comment: `$a = new DB($host, $db, $charset, $user, $pass);` не переменные передавайте, а значения конкретные в данному случае.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, согласен)) Прост забыл как создается

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
class DB
{
protected $host = 'localhost';
protected $db =   'name';
protected $charset = 'utf8';
protected $user = 'user';
protected $pass = 'pass';

public function __construct() {

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->db;charset=$this->charset";
    $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    );

    try {
        $this->DBconnect = $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $opt);
    }
    catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
        if(!empty($Exception->getCode())){
            die('Ошибка');
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Да я понял о чём Алексей говорил, так и сделал

Comment: Хардкодить параметры подключения не стоит. Переиспользовать класс гораздо практичнее, передавая разные параметры подключения извне, а не определяя потомков переопределяющих защищённые свойства.

Comment: Не встречал пока проектов, в которых требовалось бы подключение к разным БД, поэтому так захардкодил

Answer (score 4):

Это определение конструктора, его сигнатура:

```
public function __construct($host, $db, $charset, $user, $pass) {
```

А это его использование из разных мест вашего кода:

```
$a = new DB('localhost', 'my_shop', 'utf8', 'foo', 'bar');
// ...
$b = new DB('5.5.5.5', 'users', 'cp1251', 'foo', 'bar');
```

Переменные `$host, $db, $charset, $user, $pass` примут то одни, то другие значения, в зависимости от значений, с которыми вызван конструктор в каждом конкретном случае.

Хранить реквизиты внутри определения класса, как у вас тут ..

```
protected $user = 'user'; 
protected $pass = 'passw';
```

.. дурной тон. Хорошо бы вынести их в отдельный файл конфига. А ещё лучше - положить его за пределами директории, куда смотрит веб-сервер.

Comment: Да весь класс этот будет лежать в директории недоступной из веб. Но да про конфиг думал. Один вопрос только: как конфиг передать в класс? `class DB($config){` ?

Comment: Как передать - зависит от архитектуры вашего приложения. Самый простой банальный пример - положить в файл конфига массив `<?php return ['host' => 'localhost', .., ..];`, подключить его в самом начале index'а, например, так `$conf = require 'conf.php';`, и потом передавать в качестве аргументов ключи этого массива `$a = new DB($conf['host'], .., ..`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class DB
{
    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $db =   'name';
    protected $charset = 'utf8';
    protected $user = 'user';
    protected $pass = 'passw';

    public function __construct($host="", $db="", $charset="", $user="", $pass="") {
        $host = ($host == "") ? $this->host : $host;
        $db = ($db == "") ? $this->db : $db;
        $charset = ($charset == "") ? $this->charset : $charset;
        $user = ($user == "") ? $this->user : $user;
        $pass = ($pass == "") ? $this->pass : $pass;

        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );

        try {
            $this->DBconnect = $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
        }
        catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
            if(!empty($Exception->getCode())){
                die('Ошибка');
            }
        }
    }
}

    // Создаю экземпляр
$a = new DB();
?>
```

или сразу в вызове конструктора указывайте значения по умолчанию

Answer (score 0):

Обычно, файл с настройками подключения к БД хранится отдельно, и называется *(к примеру)* `db.php`. Тогда конструктор вашего класса можно существенно сократить, вызывая его вообще без параметров. Пример:

```
// Файл db.php - должен иметь такую структуру
return [
    'host'    => 'localhost';
    'db'      => 'name'; 
    'charset' => 'utf8';
    'user'    => 'user'; 
    'pass'    => 'passw';
];
```

Описание класса:

```
class DB
{
    public function __construct() {
        // Подключаем файл и импортируем переменные из его  
        // массива в текущую область видимости метода __construct()
        extract(require 'db.php');

        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );

        try {
            $this->DBconnect = $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
        } catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
            if (!empty($Exception->getCode())) {
                die('Ошибка');
            }
        }
    }
}

// Создание объекта без передачи параметров
$a = new DB;
```

Comment: Ваш подход очень негибкий. Класс зависит от db.php, который должен оказаться в include_path. Создать несколько подключений к бд (такое бывает необходимо) у вас не получится. Использовать класс для создания подключения не из конфига тоже нельзя.