# Как передать параметры для подключения в класс БД?

Tags: php, ооп

```
class DB
{
    // объявление свойств
    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $db =   'db';
    protected $charset = 'utf8';
    protected $user = 'user';
    protected $pass = 'pwd';

    public function __construct() {
        // создание подключения к БД
    }

    // другие методы класса
}
```

Варианты передать параметры которые были у меня:

1. Записать прямо в классе как в примере (сказали не кошерно)
2. Передать при создании экземпляра класса `$db = new DB($host, $db, $charset ...);` этот способ уже не нравится лично мне, постоянно надо прокидывать все переменные каждый раз и самое главное: откуда из взять что бы прокинуть? Из глобалки?
3. Положить в конфиг. Допустим. Как передать конфиг в класс минуя глобалку?
4. ... ?

Comment: Тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705994/%d0%92-%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0 уже было.

Comment: что значит "постоянно прокидывать"? Сколько раз ты собрался "прокидывать" эти параметры, что тебя это прям так замучило?

Comment: @Visman, это разные вопросы и разные ответы на них предполагаются.

Comment: @Visman 1) это мой-же вопрос 2) ответом там отвечен вариант с определением переменных внутри класса, тут я написал что этот вариант меня не устраивает 3) другие ответы там предполагают `$db = new DB($host, $db, $charset ...);` тут я написал что этот вариант меня тоже не устраивает 4) там вопрос о конструкторе чисто, а здесь о передаче параметров минуя глобальные переменные

Comment: @Ипатьев сколько надо столько и буду, может я паттерн dependency injection реализовать собираюсь и каждый класс будет сам обращаться к БД? К тому же это не снимает вопроса6 откуда брать эти переменные, особенно если их надо взять где-то внутри другого класса

Comment: @fosh4455, я знаю ,что там ваш вопрос. Чего бы я ссылку на него оставил тут? А это вопрос-дискуссия, так как вы предлагаете разные варианты ответа на него и хотите решить какой лучше с нашей помощью. И такой вопрос следует закрыть.

Comment: @Visman я могу его перефразировать так что на него можно будет один или несколько конкретных ответов

Comment: @AlexKrass, за закрытие я проголосовал не потому что это одинаковые вопросы. Ссылка дана, чтобы посетители были в курсе.

Comment: Сделайте кошерный вариант - подсмотрите реализацию с какого-нибудь фреймворка. Там есть файл конфигурации хранящий массив, класс для работы с этими файлами конфигурации и сам файл подключения. Используйте практики ведущих мировых разработчиков!

Comment: @Visman понял, я просто подумал вы дали ссылку на дупликат подобного вопроса в котором уже содержится ответ.

Comment: Как передавать -- зависит от входных требований, а они не озвучены. Допустим, если есть требование "писать тесты" -- то нужно передавать параметры подключения, а не хардкодить их или брать из конфига. Вопрос нужно закрыть, так как пока не прояснятся требования -- нельзя будет определить какой ответ является корректным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс подключения к БД

```
namespace Engine\Core\Database;

use \PDO;
use Engine\Core\Config\Config;
class Connection
    {
        private $link;

        /**
         * Connection constructor.
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->connect();
        }

        /**
         * @return $this
         */
        private function connect()
        {
            $config = Config::file('database');

            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db_name'] . ';charset=' . $config['charset'];

            $this->link = new PDO($dsn, $config['username'], $config['password']);

            return $this;

        }
        /**
         * @param $sql
         * @param array $values
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function execute($sql, $values = [])
        {
            $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);
            return $sth->execute($values);
        }
        /**
         * @param $sql
         * @param array $values
         * @return array
         */
        public function query($sql, $values = [])
        {

            $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

            $sth->execute($values);
            $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($result === false) {
                return [];
            }

            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Класс queryBuilder - на заметку возьмите.

```
namespace Engine\Core\Database;
class QueryBuilder
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $sql = [];
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $values = [];

    /**
     * @param string $fields
     * @return $this
     */
    public function select($fields = '*')
    {
        $this->reset();
        $this->sql['select'] = "SELECT {$fields} ";

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $table
     * @return $this
     */
    public function from($table)
    {
        $this->sql['from'] = "FROM {$table} ";

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $column
     * @param $value
     * @param string $operator
     * @return $this
     */
    public function where($column, $value, $operator = '=')
    {
        $this->sql['where'][] = "{$column} {$operator} ?";
        $this->values[] = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $field
     * @param $order
     * @return $this
     */
    public function orderBy($field, $order)
    {
        $this->sql['order_by'] = " ORDER BY {$field} {$order}";

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $number
     * @return $this
     */
    public function limit($number)
    {
        $this->sql['limit'] = " LIMIT {$number}";

        return $this;
    }

    public function update($table)
    {
        $this->reset();
        $this->sql['update'] = " UPDATE {$table} ";

        return $this;
    }

    public function insert($table)
    {
        $this->reset();
        $this->sql['insert'] = "INSERT INTO {$table} ";

        return $this;
    }

    public function set($data = [])
    {
        $this->sql['set'] .= " SET ";

        if (!empty($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $this->sql['set'] .= "{$key} = ?";
                if (next($data)) {
                    $this->sql['set'] .= ", ";
                }
                $this->values[] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function sql()
    {
        $sql = '';
        if (!empty($this->sql)) {
            foreach ($this->sql as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == 'where') {
                    $sql .= " WHERE ";
                    foreach ($value as $where) {
                        $sql .= $where;
                        if (count($value) > 1 and next($value)) {
                            $sql .= ' AND ';
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $sql .= $value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $sql;
    }

    public function reset()
    {
        $this->sql = [];
        $this->values = [];
    }

}
```

Потом если нужно просто в коде вызывайте

```
$this->db->execute(
                $this->queryBuilder->update($this->getTable())
                    ->set($properties)
                    ->where('id', $this->id)
                    ->sql(),
                $this->queryBuilder->values
                );
```

Данный паттерн использую у себя на сайте, думаю и вам будет полезен
Кстати, если вы хотите использовать DI

```
namespace Engine;
use Engine\DI\DI;

abstract class Controller
{
    /**
     * @var DI
     */
    protected $di;
    protected $db;


    /**
     * Controller constructor.
     * @param DI $di
     */
    public function __construct(DI $di)
    {
        $this->di       = $di;
        $this->db       = $this->di->get('db');

    }
}
```

---

Вот другие файлы (config)

```
namespace Engine\Core\Config;
class Config
{
    /**
     * @param $key
     * @param string $group
     * @return null
     */
    public static function item($key, $group = 'main')
    {
        $groupItems = static::file($group);
        return isset($groupItems[$key]) ? $groupItems[$key] : null;
    }

    /**
     * @param $group
     * @return bool|mixed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public static function file($group)
    {
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' .  mb_strtolower(ENV) . '/Config/' . $group . '.php';

        if(file_exists($path))
        {
            $items = require_once $path;

            if(!empty($items))
            {
                return $items;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new \Exception(
                    sprintf(
                        'Config file <b>%s</b> is not a valid array.', $path
                    )
                );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new \Exception(
                sprintf('Cannot load config from file, file <b>%s</b> does not exist.', $path)
            );
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Если будет что-то непонятно по коду пишите в комменты

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Да есть пара уточняющих вопросов: Как выглядит конфиг у вас? Судя по `use Engine\Core\Config\Config;` это класс? И я что-то не уловил момент, как в классе Connection внутри метода `private function connect()` у вас оказались переменные, например `$config['host']` вы их напрямую в метод не передали, через конструктор класса тоже не передали, как же они туда попадут?

Comment: в переменную coonfig вы можете свое подключить, например где-нибудь : $config['host' => 'localhost', 'user' => 'root', 'password' => '', ...]; И потом просто подключить как вам удобно. Кстати проще вначале в $this  передать все что нужно. Потом $this доступен из любой части кода если вы use подключаете

Comment: Это был фрагмент из CMS которую я пишу, у вас может быть все по другому. Это пример

Comment: `$config` у вас глобальный? Я что-то не уловил момента где вы его в `$this` передаёте

Comment: Я добавил код config-а

Answer (score 1):

один файл ини который ты парсишь

```
$config = **parse_ini_file**('config.ini', true);

// define DB configuration
$configDb = $config['db'];
define('DB_HOST', $configDb['host']);
define('DB_USER', $configDb['user']);
define('DB_PASSWORD', $configDb['password']);
define('DB_NAME', $configDb['dbname']);
define('DB_PORT', $configDb['port']);
```

ну и создаешь себе класс в котором конектишь константы))

```
$link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Дальше просто делаешь автолоад в который все закидываешь (все класы, все все файлы где хранятся константы).

это отдельный файл с настройками. который ты подключаешь ко всем страницам.

```
 require_once 'config.php';
 require_once 'DB.php';
```

Ну а вообще лучше использовать PDO - конектится не только к MySQL а к многим базам.